# Iterating in JSF, rendering plain HTML <div> elements using for each loop

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, collections, foreach, facelets

I'm using JSF 2 with Facelets. I have a managed bean that has a property referring to a `List<Employee>`. Now, I have the `<h:dataTable>` tag that can create a table out of that collection in a simple way.

What I need is something different, I need to create a `<div>` element with an `<img>` for each item in that collection. How can I achieve this in JSF 2 with Facelets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`<ui:repeat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html) to iterate over a collection while controlling the markup fully yourself. E.g.

```
private List<Employee> employees;

@EJB
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    employees = employeeService.list();
}

public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}
```

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.employees}" var="employee">
    <div><img src="#{employee.image}" /></div>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that.